# sequential or marginal type of test in anova.lme

Tags: r, anova, lme4-nlme

I used lme function of nlme package to fit a model for an unbalanced data (mixed model). There are two predictors A and B and A*B (interaction).

```
model = lme(Y ~ A * B, random = ~ 1 | ID, data = mydata, 
na.action = na.exclude, method = "ML")
```

I am interested to know which types of the "sequential" or "marginal" test for ANOVA I should use to find the main effect? and what is the differences?

```
anova.lme(model, type = "sequential")
anova.lme(model, type = "marginal")
```

The interaction effect is significant.

Comment: Thanks @aosmith I think Type II is not an option for me as there is a significant interaction. The response variables are categorical and the data is unbalanced. So maybe Type III would be the better option I guess.

Comment: There's been lots of discussion on "types" of SS on R lists in the past.  See, e.g., [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-March/230280.html).  If it makes any sense to test the main effects even though you have evidence there is an interaction, I think it's fairly safe to say you don't want sequential tests when you have unbalanced data.